# What are the names of the two shuttles and which missions were they on?

Tags: space-cowboys

What is the name of the space shuttle used in the *Space Cowboys* launch scenes? Which mission is that from?

What is the name of the space shuttle used in the landing scenes? Which mission is that from?

**Update**
The landing scenes are not from *Discovery* (at least cannot confirm), the name of that shuttle had been covered by *Daedalus* using CGI presumably.

The meatball insignia on the left wings suggest that both missions were no earlier than 1992 (the introduction of that insignia) or 1998 (the time NASA repainted their fleet). Considering the production date of the film, there are 53 missions between January 1992 to May 2000, 10 missions between January 1998 to May 2000.

Comment: You could probably reduce the number more by day/night landings. Also, the footage would have had to been harvested well before the release of the movie (but by how much is the real question) which also would narrow it down more. Just saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Launching scene

During the ignition scene, we can see that the name of that orbiter on the right wing is much longer than the flag. Since the name is not readable in that distance, I would not suspect that the film crew modified that name as well. The length of the name suggests that the orbiter is not *Atlantis*. The white wing roots indicates that the orbiter is not *Columbia*. Considering the time of that ten missions, it could only be STS-95 by *Discovery* or STS-99 by *Endeavour*. The preparation scene prior to the launch shows that the surrounding area of the meatball logo on the left wing are rather clear. ([notice the blank block above the logo on *Endeavour*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:STS-130_Endeavour_Rollout_6.jpg), it's noticeable comparing to the logo on *Discovery*'s left wing) This suggests that it is STS-95.

## Landing scene

In those ten missions between the NASA logo change and the production of the film, STS-99 is the only mission took place in the evening with flood light on the runway on. The NASA [footage](http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/rrg2.pl?video/shuttle/missions/sts-99/sts-99-land.rm) appeared to be a slight off angle from the scene. The white block on the left wing also suggests that the orbiter is *Endeavour*.

## Conclusion

Those observations show that the launch scene is taken from the actually launch scene of STS-95 and landing scene is taken from the landing scene of STS-99. The two shuttles are *Discovery* and *Endeavour*.